# WiX ScheduleReboot does not respect condition

Tags: c#, .net, wix, wix3.6, wix3.7

#### Situation

I have an application composed by a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application and a Windows Service. To install these components, I'm using WiX. Until now everything was working fine, but when I try to install on Windows XP a problem occurs.

When the installer tries to start the service before closing the installation, it does not work. I get the "user not have permission to start" message.

I removed `ServiceControl` block from the .wxs file, build again, tried installing and rebooting the pc (this on Windows XP). So now my service starts fine.

#### The Problem

I need to ask about reboot and disable `<ServiceControl>`from `<Component>`, only when Windows is XP and the Service Pack is less than 3.

So I tried this:

```
<Product>
  <!-- (...) -->
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize">
      <![CDATA[NOT (VersionNT <= 501 AND ServicePackLevel <> 3)]]>
    </ScheduleReboot>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
  <!-- (...) -->
</Product>
<!-- (...) -->
<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup>
    <Component>
      <File Id="ServExe" Name="Serv.exe" DiskId="1"
            Source="Serv.exe" KeyPath="yes"/>
      <ServiceInstall
        Id="ServiceInstaller"
        Type="ownProcess"
        Name="Serv"
        DisplayName="Serv"
        Description="Serv"
        Start="auto"
        Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]"
        Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]"
        ErrorControl="normal" />
      <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both"
                      Remove="uninstall" Name="Serv" Wait="yes" />
    </Component>
    <!-- (...) -->
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

But no matter the Windows (I tried XP, XP SP 2, XP SP 3, Windows 7), I always get the "Need Reboot" dialog. And I don't know how put a install time condition in `<ServiceControl>`.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In InstallExecuteSequence table action will be executed only when Condition is True. Try to simplify your expression like this: (VersionNT = 501 AND ServicePackLevel = 3).
You could open your msi file with Orca and check if InstallExecuteSequence table contains correct Condition record in the ScheduleReboot row.
Try to create log file of your installation and check how installer evaluated your condition.

Comment: Thanks man for the answer, but the expression that I put here hasn't the same logical value that the your suggestion. I tried to simplify but not caused any difference. In Orca the condition is the same.

Comment: I made a mistake, correct condition should be (VersionNT = 501 AND ServicePackLevel < 3). - without NOT.

Comment: ServiceControl doesn't allow to use Condition as a child element. You could try to create two Conponent items installing the same file - one for XP SP3 and greater and the second for others. But it seems to me that it is simplier to create external custom action dll that will start your service.

Comment: Now the condition is right. But you said _ServiceControl doesn't allow to use Condition as a child element._ It's not true, I remove left side of condition and works, not for my situation, but to a generic situation.